# PHP preg match/preg_replace not recognizing pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace all instances of paragraphs containing only a series of the same character with a separator tag.

I've used https://www.phpliveregex.com/ to test the code, copied the code straight from there onto php on my server AND on http://phptester.net/, but it will NOT work.

Sample:

```
$test = "<p>Sed nec convallis tortor. Aenean ante diam, aliquet eget porta in, cursus a nibh. Suspendisse eu tempus sem, sit amet malesuada arcu. Nunc condimentum a elit eget elementum. Curabitur id erat et dolor mattis luctus id id massa.</p>
<p>XXXXXXX</p>
<p><em>Nulla vel ligula arcu. Vivamus nec nisi sit amet dui vulputate suscipit.</em></p>
<p><em>Suspendisse finibus lectus ut elit molestie, ornare accumsan lacus accumsan.</em></p>
<p><em>Fusce vel blandit dolor, ac imperdiet purus.</em>.</p>";

echo preg_replace("/<p>(.)\1{3,}<\/p>/i", "<hr />", $test);
```

This will still output the `<p>XXXXXXX</p>` line, not the intended `<hr />`.

Any ideas? Tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by replacing your double quotes with single quotes.

```
echo preg_replace('/<p>(.)\1{3,}<\/p>/i', '<hr />', $test);
```

After a bit more testing with your original code will also work if you use two `\\` for the 1 in your pattern.  Like so.

```
echo preg_replace("/<p>(.)\\1{3,}<\/p>/i", "<hr />", $test);
```

I believe that this is because using double quotes is treating the `\1` as an escaped `1`.  Using two `\\` before the one escapes the backslash making it literal thus achieving the desired instruction of `\1`.  Something like that.  My regex is not all that good but I think that is what is going on.  You can avoid all this by using single quotes around your pattern.

Comment: why not just escape the `<` in the `<hr />`? seems to be the issue here.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner I tried your suggestion with his original code and was not able to get it to work. `preg_replace("/<p>(.)\1{3,}<\/p>/i", "\<hr />", $test);`  did not work for me.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry, I deleted my comment. I thought it was the OP's answer LOL!. Ok, well I was sure that was it. Oh well, can't get them all.

Comment: I was curious to see if that would do it.  Was trying to learn something from it.  I think it has to do with the double quotes not working on the backslash `\1` in the pattern.

Comment: Now that's where it stops for me, the "pattern". I know some regex but not enough to offer a concrete answer. One of the characters that is widely used in PHP is the "less than" symbol and requires special attention when it's needed in  a search pattern of sorts. That's all I know when I need to escape them but I never had to, so I just prepare, bind, execute and make sure all passwords have been dealt with properly. *Cheers*

Comment: Yeah my regex is not all that good either.  I think I figured out the reason though...   ~Cheers!

Comment: Yeah saw that. Both answers look good to me, least from what I read :-) Ok, tying up comments. Ciao for now.

Comment: Joseph, that solved it, thank you! :)

Comment: No problem, good luck with the rest of your project. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As Joseph_J pointed out, the problem is that `\1` has to be passed to the regex engine; that is a string of length 2 with the two ASCII characters "\" and "1". But in PHP `"\[0-9]{1,3}"` (in double quotes) [represents only one single character in octal notation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). So `"\1"` would be a string with a length of 1 consisting of one character with ascii value 1. Here's a small overview:

```
source code     internal string     length
"\1"            ascii code 1        1
'\1'            \1                  2
"\\1"           \1                  2
'\\1'           \1                  2
"\134\61"       \1                  2
```

If you also want to cover newlines ("containing only a series of the same character"), then a [pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) s is needed to make `.` also match newlines:

```
preg_replace('/<p>(.)\1*<\/p>/is', '<hr />', $test);
```

Comment: steffen, removing the \1 will make the pattern also match "<p>abcdefg</p>", which is not my goal. Joseph's solution does the trick.

Comment: @dudah84 Haha, missed that part :-) I updated my answer accordingly.